# Rails: Insert a resource and at the same time being able to insert subresources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I'm a Rails beginner.

I have a problem with it, but first, here's an image to explain what I want to do:

[image: Wireframe]

*Verbally*: I'm struggling to have a new page for a resource, where I can add —inside it— associated subresources.

When I click on `add new subresource`, I'd like to get on the  **new page** for the subresource. After clicking on save, with the field completed, I should get redirected back to the new resource page, and I should see inside it the newly associated subresource.

I tried to insert this line of code in the resource new form:

```
link_to 'New Sub Resource', new_resource_sub_resource_path(@resource)
```

But when I click, it returns something like:

```
No route matches {:resource_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:resource_id]
```

Clearly, the resource is not still saved so it complains because it doesn't have an Id... is this solvable? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If I were on your boots, I would approach this problem using `form_tag`, and then, once in the `Resource#create` controller action, I would first create the `Resource` and then iterate through all the subresources to create them.

In order to have all the `Subresource` embedded in the submitted form I would make use of jQuery/JS.
I created an example that can help you code your `app/views/resources/new.html.erb` file. Even though I used plain HTML/JS, I'm sure it can help you and hopefully it won't be too hard to port to `ERB` :)

http://jsfiddle.net/CV3tf/1/

Something like:

```rb
#app/controllers/resources_controller.rb
def create
  @resource=Resource.create(params[:resource])
  params[:subresource].each do |s|
    #Assuming Resource has_many Subresources
    @resource.subresources.create(s) 
  end
end
```

**Please note** that the `params` hash must be appropiately filled in the form *view*. This is just a basic conceptual scaffold.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) on this subject, as well as a gem, that simplifies nested model forms: [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

They use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to handle the creation of the main resource and sub resources and javascript to create partial sub forms on request.